# responsive table with chosen: chosen-drop got cut off behind table

Tags: html, css, jquery-chosen

I'm using responsive table from this [site](http://codepen.io/geoffyuen/pen/FCBEg) with chosen select multiple.

Here is the rwd-table css file with slightly modified. But nothing much, I just change the layout color.

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document for Responsive Table*/
.rwd-table {
  margin: 1em 0;
  min-width: 300px;
  width:auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.rwd-table tr {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.rwd-table th {
  display: none;
}
.rwd-table td {
  display: block;
}
.rwd-table td:first-child {
  padding-top: .5em;
}
.rwd-table td:last-child {
  padding-bottom: .5em;
}
.rwd-table td:before {
  content: attr(data-th) ": ";
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 6.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}
@media (min-width: 650px) {
  .rwd-table td:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
  text-align: left;
}
@media (min-width: 650px) {
  .rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: .25em .5em;
  }
  .rwd-table th:first-child, .rwd-table td:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .rwd-table th:last-child, .rwd-table td:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

.rwd-table {
  color: #545454;
  border-radius: .4em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.rwd-table tr {
  border-color: #dddddd;
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
  margin: .5em 1em;
}
@media (min-width: 650px) {
  .rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
    padding: 0.5em 1em !important;
  }
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td:before {

}
```

The only thing not working is the chosen-drop cut off behind the table. I've been trying to change the z-index but not working.

I put up the code at jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yodann/nggqghk6/)

If anyone can help me out, would be much appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have split  CSS for the same selections as follows :

```
.rwd-table {
  margin: 1em 0;
  min-width: 300px;
  width:auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.rwd-table tr {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.rwd-table th {
  display: none;
}
.rwd-table td {
  display: block;
}
```

And

```
.rwd-table {
  color: #545454;
  border-radius: .4em;
  overflow: hidden; // <<<<<<<<<< overflow causing the problem
}
.rwd-table tr {
  border-color: #dddddd;
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
  margin: .5em 1em;
}
```

In the second bit of code, your are setting the table overflow as hidden, that's why your chosen are being hidden..

It is good practice to combine the CSS for the same selectors in one place in order to prevent ambiguity.

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nggqghk6/8/)

Comment: ahh... i see. the code was given like that by the creator. but i should have notice that. Thank KAD